# How to filter the Parents ID by its children foreign key?

Tags: django, filter

views

```
def Parents_login_form(request):
   if request.method != 'POST':
      raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')
   try:
        m = ParentsProfile.objects.get(Parent_User=request.POST['p_user'])
        if m.Parent_Password == request.POST['p_pass']:
            aa = request.POST['p_user']
            parents = ParentsProfile.objects.all().filter(Parent_User=aa)

            student = request.POST.get('parentsID')
            students = StudentProfile.objects.filter(Parent_Users = student)
            print(students)
            return render(request, 'accounts/ParentsProfile.html', {"parents": parents, "students": students})

   except ParentsProfile.DoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the error below.')

   return render(request, 'accounts/Plogin_form.html')
```

html

```
{% for me in parents %}
 <input type="hidden" value="{{me.id}}" name="parentsID" id="parentsID" onchange="" readonly>
{% endfor %}
```

model

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    Parent_Users = models.ForeignKey(ParentsProfile, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, y is fields in parent model, x is fields in child:

```
{% for y in parents %}
{% for x in y.+.all %}

<input type="hidden" value="{{y.id}}" name="parentsID" id="parentsID" onchange="" readonly>

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Replace 'students.+.all' with ''parents.x.all' --- if that doesn't work, post full modals, I can figure out from there.

Comment: {% for me in parent%}
<table>
<input type="text" value="{{me.id}}" name="parentsID" id="parentsID" onchange="" readonly>
<h2> {{me.Fathers_Firstname}}  {{me.Fathers_Lastname}}</h2></center>
{% for da in students %}
<tr>
<td text-align="center"><img src="{{da.Image.url}}" width="33%" height="120px"><br>
{{da.Firstname}}  {{da.Middle_Initial}}  {{da.Lastname}}
<a href="#"><br><i ></i>My Medical Record</a>
<a href="#"><br><i>Enroll</i></a>
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endfor %}

Comment: can you apply your solution using that html?

Comment: Sry I was asleep. No you don't have to change your views. I edited my answer above

Comment: error Could not parse the remainder: '+.all' from 'y.+.all'

Comment: sir please apply you solution here

Comment: {% for me in parent%} <table> <input type="text" value="{{me.id}}" name="parentsID" id="parentsID" onchange="" readonly> <h2> {{me.Fathers_Firstname}} {{me.Fathers_Lastname}}</h2></center> {% for da in students %} <tr> <td text-align="center"><img src="{{da.Image.url}}" width="33%" height="120px"><br> {{da.Firstname}} {{da.Middle_Initial}} {{da.Lastname}} <a href="#"><br><i ></i>My Medical Record</a> <a href="#"><br><i>Enroll</i></a> </td> </tr> {% endfor %} </table> {% endfor %}

Comment: change that related_name='+' to something other than a + ... the word 'foo' for example .. It's trying to treat the code as mathematical addition

Comment: And i cant do that unless you post both modals ... student & parent ... otherwise i cant know the fields